# Responsive design: Website 100% wide moves left and right outside the device

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design

I am finishing a Web project which should be, as usual, mobile friendly. Responsive.

All the elements are responsive, so in smartphones the content is clearly displayed and readable, however in Smartphones the site is shaky. It means I could move it left or right, like the main-container is not "fixed" to 100% the width of the device. See the picture

[image]

Once I left the pressure over the screen, it returns to the "good position and it is all readable. No element is outside the screen.

**How could I actually avoid this effect**

I using Wordpress 4.8.3 , Bootstrap 3.3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by an overflowing element. Find the element by applying:

```
* {
  border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

Then see why it is breaking out of it's container. Maybe you have not put it in a row or column correctly, missing closing tag etc.

A link to your site or the code would be very helpful.

Comment: Oh, Thanks. Now I see clearly the element. Unfortunately the site is still not deployed, so I can not past here a link to access to it